# wxPython - refreshing / updating part of the GUI

Tags: wxpython, refresh, panel

I use a GridBagSizer with several cells containing a StaticTextCtrl. Some of these texts need to be changed depending on user behaviour. So I need to update the GUI when a change is made.
The GridBagSizer is definded in a function that is called by a function in another class, which in turn is called during GUI assembly. To illustrate this, here is a code snippet:

```
class SampleClass(wx.MiniFrame):

    [...some other code...]

    def makeGUI(self):
        # make panels
        panelFoo = self.makePanelFoo()
        panelBar = self.makePanelBar()
        panelFinal = self.makePanelFinal()

        # pack elements
        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.mainSizer.Add(panelFoo, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.mainSizer.Add(panelBar, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.mainSizer.Add(panelFinal, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)

        # fit layout
        self.mainSizer.Fit(self)
        self.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)
    # ----


    [...some other code...]

    def makePanelFinal(self):

        panel = Canvas(self, -1)

        # define canvas parts     
        self.partA = panel.makePartA()        
        self.partB = panel.makePartB()
        self.partC = panel.makePartC()

        # arrange canvas parts
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        mainSizer.Add(self.partA, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, mwx.PANEL_SPACE_MAIN)
        mainSizer.Add(self.partB, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT, mwx.PANEL_SPACE_MAIN)
        mainSizer.Add(self.partC, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.LEFT|wx.RIGHT|wx.BOTTOM, mwx.PANEL_SPACE_MAIN)        

        # fit layout
        mainSizer.Fit(panel)
        panel.SetSizer(mainSizer)

        return panel
    # ----


class Canvas(panel):

    [...some other code...]

    def makePartC(self):

        sizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(wx.StaticBox(self, -1, ""), wx.VERTICAL)
        grid = wx.GridBagSizer(mwx.GRIDBAG_VSPACE, mwx.GRIDBAG_HSPACE)

        [...some code where the GridBagSizer is made...]

        sizer.Add(grid, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.ALL, 5)

        return sizer
```

I now need to define a function in the class `Canvas` (or must this be placed in class `SampleClass`?) that will be called when a change in the GUI is neccessary:

```
    def updateCanvas(self):
        ??? .Refresh() ???   
    # ----
```

Could someone please give me a hint which commands I should use?

Thanks, Woodpicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is call the StaticText's SetLabel method to update it. I don't usually recommend doing the whole parent.widget.SetLabel() thing though as that can get pretty ugly pretty quickly. It does work, but I prefer using pubsub myself. You can read about that here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/

EDIT: For example, you could have the receiver set up like this:

```
Publisher().subscribe(self.updateDisplay, ("update.display"))
```

Then in the function, you'd do something like this:

```
def updateDisplay(self, msg):
    self.myStaticTxtCtrl.SetLabel(msg.data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the interesting webpage on pubsub. In this example, self.showFrame is called. What function would this need to be be in my case? Can I somehow bind the StaticTextCtrl to the Publisher().subscribe()?

Comment: You can call the function whatever you like, such as updateStaticText(self, fName). Then just pass it the data you need from the pubsub handler.

Comment: Yes, of course I can call the function whetever I like - but then my problem comes: What should this function do? In my case the first step in this function would be to redefine my `StsticTextCtrl`. And then? How do I get this change displayed in the GUI (StaticTextCtrl in GridBagSizer in StaticBoxSizer in BoxSizer in BoxSizer). What command could I give here? Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer slightly...hopefully that will show you what I'm talking about. Also read the documentation. It says how to change the control's value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save a reference to the `wxStaticText` in your `GridBagSizer` and then update the control with the new text.

Here is an example with a `FlexGridSizer`:

```
self.fNameC = wx.StaticText(self, -1, fn)
fgs = wx.FlexGridSizer(5, 2, 5, 5)
fgs.Add(self.fNameC, 0, wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL)
```

later on I do this:

```
self.panel.fNameC.SetLabel(fName)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am still confused. Does SetLabel also change your GUI? Seems as if I still do something wrong - all the changes I make to the StaticText lead to changes in the field (I can test this by printing the values), but the changes are not reflected in the GUI?!  Where do you call SetLabel? In the same function, in another function? Does my nesting across the classes cause the problem?